# JS - Setting Div background color using a variable

Tags: javascript, html, colors

Well basically, one of my mates was practicing JS and he had an idea of a test basic site. So I said we would have a race to complete it. We have both run in to an error at this point. We have created a color in JS. However when we need to output it does not work. I have this.

```
document.getElementById("outputColor").style.backgroundColor=currentColor;
```

Where current color is made via this

```
part1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
part2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
part3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
currentColor = "\"rgb (" + part1 + ", " + part2 + ", " + part3 + ")\"";
```

Putting current color in "" would mean it's expecting the value of currentColor. Not the actual variable value.

Hope that makes sense. Is this possible, or are we barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks

Edit:
It does have a css style assosiated with it already

```
#outputColor
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

Edit: Solved, solution is

```
currentColor = "rgb(" + part1 + ", " + part2 + ", " + part3 + ")";
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are too much double-quotes, use this:

```
currentColor = "rgb(" + part1 + ", " + part2 + ", " + part3 + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks, that was almost it just had one to many spaces after rgb. Correct answer is `currentColor = "rgb(" + part1 + ", " + part2 + ", " + part3 + ")";` 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
currentColor = "rgba(" + part1 + ", " + part2 + ", " + part3 + ",0)";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
currentColor = "rgb(" + part1 + ", " + part2 + ", " + part3 + ")"; // RGB
```

OR Using Hex format

```
currentColorHex="#"+(part1).toString(16)+(part2).toString(16)+(part3).toString(16);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/WTWGH/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however Dr.Molle beat you to it. I managed to get it from his. You are correct and thanks for your reply. +1'd