# change color using input range element

Tags: javascript

trying to give color value using slider.there will be four slider,they are red,green,blue,alpha.everything seems fine but it is not changing the color of the div having  id "mydiv".what could be the problem?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var red=0;
            var green=0;
            var blue=0;
            var alpha=0;
            function changered(val){
                red=val;
                var m=document.getElementById("mydiv");
                m.style.backgroundColor='rgba ('+red+','+green+','+blue+','+alpha+')';
            }
            function changegreen(val){
                green=val;
                var m=document.getElementById("mydiv");
                m.style.backgroundColor='rgba ('+red+','+green+','+blue+','+alpha+')';
            }
            function changeblue(val){
                blue=val;
                var m=document.getElementById("mydiv");
                m.style.backgroundColor='rgba ('+red+','+green+','+blue+','+alpha+')';
            }
            function changealpha(val){
                alpha=val;
                var m=document.getElementById("mydiv");
                m.style.backgroundColor='rgba ('+red+','+green+','+blue+','+alpha+')';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="mydiv"  style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;"></div></br>
        <div style="background-color:black;color:white;display:inline-block;background-color:red;">
            red:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changered(this.value);"></br>
            green:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changegreen(this.value);"></br>
            blue:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changeblue(this.value);"></br>
            alpha:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changealpha(this.value);"></br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things that are wrong with your code :

1 - `Alpha` value expects a decimal between 0-1 so correct alpha input should be

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1"  value="0" step="0.01" onChange="changealpha(this.value);">
```

2 - You have an extra space in your rgba usage like: `rgba (` . But this space between `a` and `(` shouldnt be there : `rgba(...`

3- Those are just suggestions :

Dont use `var m=document.getElementById("mydiv");` in every function but declare that `m` var before the functions as a global.

Dont write your functions seperately since all they are doing is eventually same thing. Your functions can be merge into one like this

```
function changeColor(val,color){
  switch (color) {
    case 0: red = val; break;
    case 1: green = val; break;
    case 2: blue = val; break;
    case 3: alpha = val; break;
  }
  m.style.backgroundColor='rgba('+red+','+green+','+blue+','+alpha+')';
}
```

And of course to use this function u need to call it from inputs like

```
changeColor(this.value, 0);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xGAJ8/)**

Answer (score 2):

eliminate the space between `rgba` and `(`

wrong code

```
m.style.backgroundColor='rgba ('+ //...
```

right code

```
m.style.backgroundColor='rgba('+ //...
```

and check again after changing alpha value to 255

Comment: This is exactly the right answer for the code incorrectness, but for visibility, you must add @Kyo's answer...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

Your alpha is 0. Make it 1 by default to remove confusion:

```
var alpha = 1;
```

, and also there shouldn't be space for the function 'rgba('.

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPfNK/11/)

Comment: Not sure if you saw @AshokGj's answer before posting this one, but in your fiddle, you also employed his correcting suggestion to remove the space between `rgba` and `(`... it wouldn't work without that correction...

Comment: The reference was taken from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067516/js-setting-div-background-color-using-a-variable

Comment: don't forget to give credit / thank to those who helped you... you're welcome ;)

Comment: I gave mine to @BatuZet it's the full and precise answer... ;)

Comment: ah, and alpha shouldn't be 255 but 1